# capture group from a string

Tags: regex

I have a string with something like this

```
Item 1: MacBook Pro Price 1000€ Item 2: MacBook Air Price 900€ Item 3: iPad 300€ Infinity Loop 1
```

I want a regex with 3 matches, each with two groups.

- MacBook Pro, 1000€
- MacBook Air, 900€
- iPad, 300€

Comment: You need namely groups? Or matches? 

Comment: You are right, I need matches with groups.

Answer (score 2):

This regex does your job. But what you want to match in group appears a little weird as no general matching requirements are given. Here is the regex,

```
Item 1:\s+(.*?)\s*Price.*?:\s+(.*?)\s*Price.*:\s+([^\d]+)\s+\d+
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/FJkWvO/2)**

If the given string by OP was this,

```
Item 1: MacBook Pro Price 1000€ Item 2: MacBook Air Price 900€ Item 3: iPad Price 300€ Infinity Loop 1
```

Then regex would have been more consistent and written like this,

```
Item 1:\s+(.*?)\s*Price.*?:\s+(.*?)\s*Price.*:\s+([^\d]+)\s*Price
```

**[Demo with expected string where iPad is followed by Price](https://regex101.com/r/FJkWvO/3)**

Comment: What if for third item there will be a space? For instance `Cool iPad`?

Comment: Well, like you can see this regex is pretty much specific to the given string as there aren't any specific delimiter rules and what it should have matched. In case it was `Cool iPad` I would have safely used `[^\d]` instead of `[^ ]` at the end and the regex would have become `Item 1:\s+(.*?)\s*Price.*?:\s+(.*?)\s*Price.*:\s+([^\d]+)\s+\d+`

Comment: Thank you! I think I understand the problem a little better.

Comment: @SebastianSemmler: Yes, I guess you got it. In your string for third group capture, `iPad` should have been followed by `Price` just like others first two groups. That way the regex would have been more consistent but it works well anyway if the patter of your string remains similar. Updated my answer with updated regex if `iPad` was followed by `Price`

Answer (score 0):

```
var s = @"Item 1: MacBook Pro Price 1000€ Item 2: MacBook Air Price 900€ Item 3: Cool iPad 300€ Infinity Loop 1";
var pattern = @"Item\s\d+:\s((?'name'.+?)\s(?'price'\d+€))";
var matches = Regex.Matches(s, pattern);
foreach(Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Match: {match.Value}");
    Console.WriteLine("\tGroups:");
        Console.WriteLine($"\t\t{match.Groups["name"].Value}");
        Console.WriteLine($"\t\t{match.Groups["price"].Value}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Item 1: MacBook Pro Price 1000,00€ Item 2: MacBook Air Price 900,00€ Item 3: iPad Price 300,00€ Infinity Loop 1
```

I found a solution. I have multiple matches, each with the two capture groups I need.

```
(?<=Item\s\d: )(\w.*?) Price (\d*?,\d+?€)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/UJPpvF/4)